# sql to find the weekdays in the month from the current day

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

please help me with this. using SQL server 2008
I need to find the number of sales done on the current day.
then find the weekday from current date and based on that find the average of the sales on all those particular weekdays in the last month
ex:

```
select count(sales) from salestable where orderdate= getdate()
```

where it gives the count of the sales done on the current date
then I need to find out the average of the sales done on the same weekday for ex if today is Sunday find the average of the sales done in the last month on all Sundays in that month.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend that you borrow the data warehousing technique of creating a Calendar table that you pre-populate with 1 row for every date within the range you might need. You can add to it basically any column that is useful - in this case DayOfWeek and MonthID. Then you can eliminate date math entirely and use joins - sort of like this (not complete but points you in the right direction):

```
select count(salestable.sales) as salescount, a.salesavg
from salestable 
join calendar on salestable.orderdate = calendar.calendardate
join (
  select monthid, dayofweek, avg(salestable.sales) as salesavg
  from salestable
  join calendar on salestable.orderdate = calendar.calendardate
  group by monthid, dayofweek) as a
on calendar.monthid = a.monthid and calendar.dayofweek = a.dayofweek
where calendar.calendardate = getdate()
```

You create and populate the calendar table once and reuse it every time you need to do date operations. Once you get used to this technique, you will NEVER go back to date math.

Comment: I ran out of time to finish the SQL - it's directionally correct, but if you are trying to use this technique and still need clarification, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of queries are [Common Table Expressions](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx) very usefull. Then you can use [DATEPART](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx) function to get day of week.

Answer (score 0):

This solution is also untested and intended to just point you in the right direction.

This solution uses a co-related sub-query to get the average sales.

```
select 
    order_date, 
    count(sales) total_sales,
    (select avg(sales) 
        from sales_table 
        where order_date between dateadd(day,-30,@your_date) and @your_date
            and datepart(WEEKDAY,order_date) = datepart(WEEKDAY,@your_date)
     ) avg_sales_mth
from sales_table
where order_date = @your_date
```